# How can I avoid substr() break the html tag?

Tags: php, html, regex

Here is my code:

```
$desc = "this <br>is a test";
$maxLen = 7;
$structured_desc = "<span>" . mb_substr($desc, 0, $maxLen) . "</span>" . mb_substr($desc, $maxLen);
echo $structured_desc;
```

Here is the result of code above:

```
// output: <span>this <b</span>r>is a test
```

Now I want to avoid happening this. I mean, `</span>` must not be added in the middle of `<br>` tag.

**Note:** I guarantee the string is **only** containing `<br>` tag.

So, the `</span>` tag should be added either before or after `<br>` tag if there is any accident between them (preferably before that).

Any idea how can I do that?

---

Here is the expected result:

```
// expected output: <span>this </span><br>is a test
```

Comment: So it means you want </span> tags added in string.

Comment: could you clarify: _if there is any accident between them_?

Comment: @jibsteroos I meant in the concatenation line (line 3), if there is a overlap between `<span>` and `<br>`

Comment: Add tag span to the string and the use _str_replace('<br>','<br></span>',$desc);_ N.b. This works only if you have one br in your string

Comment: if the `<br>` is near the end of the string should all preceeding words be within the span? Will there be only 1 `<br>` per line?

Comment: @RamRaider The `<br>` is a optional tag in the string .. it can be omitted (not exists in the string)

Answer (score 1):

You can handle that by adding a `preg_replace()` right after the concatenation line. Here is the pattern:

```
/<([^>]*)<\/span>([^>]*)>/
```

#### [Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nkgwZc/2)

---

[**Full code:**](https://3v4l.org/nIEc2)

```
$desc = "this <br>is a test";
$maxLen = 7;
$structured_desc = "<span>" . mb_substr($desc, 0, $maxLen) . "</span>" . mb_substr($desc, $maxLen);
$structured_desc = preg_replace('/<([^>]*)<\/span>([^>]*)>/', '<span><$1$2>', $structured_desc);
echo $structured_desc;

//=> <span>this <span><br>is a test
```